# JSON everything i try to print becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I expected my code to return the names and ages 4 times for each user. But everytime I run this code it just returns `"Undefined"`.

```
{
     "USERS": [
      {
        "name": "RandomHuman",
        "age": 20,
      },
      {
        "name": "luisgamer23",
        "age": 23
      },
      {
        "name": "Developer",
        "age": 25,
      },
      {
       "name": "Gamer",
       "age": 18,
      }`
    ]
}
```

```
function UpdateItemList(){
 for(let i = 0; i < Object.keys(USERS).length; i++){
   console.log(USERS[i])
  }
}

UpdateItemList()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to get up and running.

Note that there are syntax errors in your code (including stray backticks, etc.). You can paste your code into the console in Chrome and debug each of the errors.

```js
function UpdateItemList(myUSERS){

  for(let i = 0; i < myUSERS.USERS.length; i++){
      console.log(myUSERS.USERS[i]);
   }
}

var myUSERS = {"USERS" : [
  {
    "name": "RandomHuman",
    "age": 20,
  },
  {
    "name": "luisgamer23",
    "age": 23,
  },
  {
    "name": "Developer",
    "age": 25,
  },
  {
   "name": "Gamer",
   "age": 18,
  }
]};

UpdateItemList(myUSERS);
```

Comment: Thanks! it seemed to work, Sorry im pretty new to json but im getting the hang of it

Comment: Trailing commas aren't a syntax error in JS, only in JSON.  But there is no JSON in either the question or this answer, only JS objects.